# Требует ли контроллер Spring наличие констуктора?

Tags: java-ee, spring-mvc

В программировании довольно давно, но в тупик поставил довольно таки скромный вопрос. Требует ли Spring наличие конструктора в контроллере или нет? Кто как думает?

```
@Controller
public class CtrListEdit {
    //нужен ли он?
    public CtrListEdit() {}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конструктор по умолчанию без аргументов и с пустым телом можно опустить, так как он просто захломляет код и не несёт никакого смысла.

Однако иногда он бывает полезен, например для инъекции сервисов:

```
@Controller
public class CtrListEdit {
    private UserService userSercvice;

    @Autowired
    public CtrListEdit(UserService userService) {
       this.userService = userService;
    }
}
```